# sqlalchemy limit the results returned from first join and have subsequent joins only join on the limited results

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Without running a sub query. Is there a way to limit the results of a particular join in a query with sqlalchemy such that any subsequent joins in the query only join off of those results? For instance i want the first 5 results of the first join, and then join the second table on the results of the first.

I have tried sticking the limit in the middle hoping ORM would understand, but this does not work

```
result = t1.query.filter_by(
                field1="something"
            ).join(
                t2, t1.id == t2.other_id
            ).limit(5).join(
                t3, t2.id == t3.other_id
            ).add_columns(
                t1.title
            ).all()
```

This might be a general SQL question as i am new to SQL and dont know if its possible to do this without a subquery.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this can be done with a [subquery](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery):

```
subquery = t1.query.filter_by(field1="something").subquery()

query = t1.outerjoin(
    sub_query,
    and_(sub_query.c.some_column == t1.some_column)
)
```